# Send Json object data one after other to the server(which does not accepts Json Array)

Tags: android, json

I have a `SQLite` data which should be sent to the server which accepts `JSON`. If I use JSON Object it is posting only one data and if I use `JSON` array the server is not accepting. The problem here is I can't change server side.
Help me out by providing some suggestions.

**JSON code**

```
private String getQuery() throws UnsupportedEncodingException,JSONException{

    Cursor a = sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM Table");
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();




        if(c.moveToFirst()) {


            do {

                jobj.put("credated_dt", a.getString(6));

                jobj.put("emp_code", a.getString(5));

                jobj.put("location", a.getString(3));

                jobj.put("name", a.getString(1));

                jobj.put("phone", a.getString(2));
                jobj.put("remarrks", a.getString(4));

            }

            while (a.moveToNext());
        }


    return jobj.toString();

}
```

**HTTPURLCONNECTION**

```
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
 BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new 
 OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
 bufferedWriter.write(getQuery());
 bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                int statusCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();


                Log.d("this", " The status code is " + statusCode);

                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                    String response = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                    Log.d("this", "The response is " + response);
                    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
                    return response;
                }
```

Comment: If the server does not support the upload of multiple records in one request and you can't change that there is no other way then to do it in several requests ...

Comment: The suggestion is sending multiple requests is not the good approach.Better you can retrieve query as `JSONArray` sting and send to the server side.It will be a good approach.M

Comment: I have a idea like once it got connected send each data one at a time to the server after getting request send another data until the rows or the data in sqlite is empty @Henry

Comment: I have a idea like once it got connected send each data one at a time to the server after getting request send another data until the rows or the data in sqlite is empty @R2R

Answer (score 0):

first add values to jsonArray then convert that array to jsonObject like this:

```
JsonObject jsonObject= new JsonObject();


 jsonObject.put("your tag",(Object)your jsonarray);
```

now pass this jsonobject to server...

Comment: I am able to do this ... but i have multiple data and i can't use json Array...once see my code  @WaleedAsim

Comment: put all multiple data to jsonArray if its not working for you then you need to hit server again and again to add data using thread approach